# How to prevent Bootstrap 4 table-responsive to overflow it's parent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 `table table-responsive` classes to get table to show horizontal scrollbar so it doesn't overflow it's parent container when table's width is larger.

However, the problem is it overflows it's parent container and doesn't show scrollbar at all.

`table-layout:fixed;` is not a solution as it fixes table's width instead of making it scrollable

```css
body {
  background: #999;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  background: #333;
  width: 100%;
}

.div-with-table {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div-with-table">
    <table class="table table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          xxxxx
        </td>
        <td>
          xxxxx
        </td>
        <td>
          xxxx
        </td>
        <td>
          xxxx xxxx
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
        <td>
          x
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/simPod/pen/PJPBEZ

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `table-responsive` class have to be declared in the table container, not in the table element: `<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table">...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Popper.js and we documented it [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/site/docs/4.1/components/tooltips.md#overflow-auto-and-scroll) and now it's in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#usage).

You simply have to change `boundary` to something else than `scrollParent`

```
$('#example').tooltip({ boundary: 'window' })
```

Answer (score 0):

What about add this rule:

```
.parent { overflow-x: scroll; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. It works in this isolated example :/. I have updated a pen a bit so there's no fixed width https://codepen.io/simPod/pen/PJPBEZ I'd rather get the `table-responsive` to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  background: #333;
  overflow-x: auto; 
  }
```

or :

```
   .parent {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  background: #333;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  }
```

or simply :

```
  .parent {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  background: #333;
  overflow: auto; 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. It works in this isolated example :/. I have updated a pen a bit so there's no fixed width https://codepen.io/simPod/pen/PJPBEZ I'd rather get the `table-responsive` to work.

Comment: just add   ' overflow: auto;'  to '.parent'  it will work when it will appear an overflow. To make it scrollable for the height you have to give a value to a height : 'height:400px; overflow:auto; ' for ex; when 'overflow: auto' does not work for itself , I think it's the same for width.

Comment: I tried to add `overflow: auto' to parent rule into codepen above but it does basically nothing.